# Are there any "special" image compression algorithms for face cases?

Tags: algorithm, image, video, compression

Are there any "special" image compression algorithms for face cases? So i'm creating a conference programm I want to transfer images (or videos) of talking heads through the internet.  Are there any special algorithms to compress images/videos of talking heads so to make them smaller (like special voice compression algorithms)?

Comment: why not using proven and advanced algorithm such as video codec that conform to H.264 or similar?

Comment: point is to use  proven and advanced algorithm such as video codec that conform to H.264 or similar but after some imagemanipulation that will prepare image for more fast and effective compression.

Comment: since you are doing it for video, i think optimizing the image compression, in this case is I-Frame of H.264 won't do any significant improvement, since video mostly get efficient compression its by temporal coherence (on P/B-Frame). so it would be better if you just send the part of heads that moving, for example the lips when the object is talking

Answer (score 1):

Really not my field, but I know that a couple of researchers from my university work on a compression algorithm that shows impressive results on limited domains (such as faces). They have published a few articles explaining the algorithms, as well as released a Matlab plugin for it.

The algorithm is called K-SVD, and you can read more about it [in the basic article](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~elad/publications/journals/2004/32_KSVD_IEEE_TSP.pdf). There are many follow-up articles published as well.

For the implementation, check out:

- [Prof. Elad's Software page](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~elad/software/)
- [Prof. Rubinstein Software Page](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~ronrubin/software.html)

Answer (score 0):

Jörgen Ahlberg at Linköping University, Sweden, wrote a PhD thesis on the subject in 2002:

J. Ahlberg, Model-based Coding - Extraction, Coding, and Evaluation of Face Model Parameters , PhD Thesis No. 761, Dept. of Electrical Engineering, Linköping University, Sweden, 2002.

It appears the technology has been moved to http://www.visagetechnologies.com/

***Edit***
The algorithm Jören developed is called Candide-3, more info on the algorithm is available at http://www.icg.isy.liu.se/candide/

Comment: they sell products- not algorithms=( btw here I can ot see direct link to paper\text file. and I need some algorithm just to compress image - not to turn hads to 3d... so to say a quick way to kick some not needed data from image asuming there is had in it and then be able to compress thatresulting image to jpeg or something else for example...